# Missing template arguments when passing a map by reference

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have the following method header:

`bool ParseMessage(char* buffer, int &fromNode, map<int, string> &messages, const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512, const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 20, const char* const DELIMITER = "#");`

I'm trying to call the method with: 
`rnod->parser.ParseMessage("@3702~10~Hi", from, &messages);`

where messages is:
`map<int, string> messages;`

But I keep getting an error: *error: missing template arguments before ‘)’ token
  rnod->parser.ParseMessage("@3702~10~Hi", from, &messages);*

Answer (score 0):

it should be messages not &messages in `rnod->parser.ParseMessage("@3702~10~Hi", from, &messages);`
 &messages actually pass the address of messages

Comment: Right, in the line you suggested just now `rnod->parser.ParseMessage("@3702~10~Hi", from, messages);` fails just as gloriously :)

Answer (score 0):

What about removing that double const before DELIMITER? Template functions are compiled only when used and so some syntax errors definitions are shown only when the function is used.

```
bool ParseMessage(char* buffer, int &fromNode, map<int, string> &messages, const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512, const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 20, const char* DELIMITER = "#");
```

And then yes, use messages (not &message) when calling the function.